# Windows 7 unidentified network direct cable connection

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have 2 computers. Both are Windows 7 and are connected directly by a cable.
There's no DHCP server and both have static IP (192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.3).

Windows 7 defines my network as an **unidentified** and I'm unable to change network local from **Public** to **Home**.
Network adapters are working fine but due to Public networks limitation I can't share folders.

Has anyone ever direct connected 2 Windows 7 computers?

Comment: What about the subnet mask? Are they both the same on each of the computers?

Answer (score 5):

Unidentified network is a network with out a valid gateway. So, set the gateway of each the computer to the other computer's IP address. Once you have done this, you should be able to change Private to Home and begin file sharing.

Also make sure you are using a cross-over cable instead of straight-though. Directly connecting 2 nodes/hosts of the same [OSI layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) requires a Ethernet cross-over cable. Added even though you probably knew this already. You never know.

*Will update my answer if more information is provide.*

Comment: The fake gateway trick works! Thanks. (FYI: you don't need a cross-over cable if at least one of the two hosts is connected via gigabit ethernet)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/dimeby8/archive/2009/06/10/change-unidentified-network-from-public-to-work-in-windows-7.aspx