# How to Solve the "Unidentified network" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 unidentified network direct cable connection](https://superuser.com/questions/71922/windows-7-unidentified-network-direct-cable-connection)

I connect the internet through Ad-hoc network, My machine uses win7 and another uses winows xp, There's no problem when I connect the XP machine, but if i disconnect and reconnect the net, then my local network is marked as "Unidentified network",unless restart the XP machine, I don't know why?

Comment: Have you diagnosed ? and check these similar questions:http://superuser.com/questions/71922/windows-7-unidentified-network-direct-cable-connection ; http://superuser.com/questions/60054/windows-7-unidentified-network-problem-cannot-connect-to-the-internet

Comment: Possible Dup: http://superuser.com/questions/71922/

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify which computer has the internet connection? If the Windows 7 computer is the one sharing the ad-hoc network to the Windows XP computer, you might want to look into using [Connectify](http://connectify.me/) instead of running an ad-hoc with internet connection sharing. Connectify uses windows 7's built-in support for emulating an access point to allow you to share an internet connection with just a laptop wireless card, but appear as a regular AP, not an ad-hoc. It is much less buggy than ICS, in my experience. I haven't used it since the beta, but it's free, and I recall it working pretty well even back then.

Comment: the Windows XP computer is the one sharing the ad-hoc network, i don't know why if i disconnect the windows XP computer, and reconnect it angin then the "Unidentified network" appears?